# Haskell binding for hunspell

Tags: haskell, hunspell

Is there a Haskell binding for the Hunspell spell checking library?

If not, is it possible to send the words to check to the Hunspell CLI program and retrieve the results?

Comment: boldface should not be used to stress an entire question. Only to specify certain parts.

Comment: Google says no, and yes. (But you should give details about what you've tried, not just the problem itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to your second question:

> If not, is it possible to send the words to check to the Hunspell CLI program and retrieve the results?

You can use the [shelly](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly) library to call any cli program in your PATH.
Assume *foo* is your program and *param1*, *param2* and *param3* are the needed parameters: `foo param1 param2 param3` would be the call in a OS shell.

Here is a small Haskell example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Shelly
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = shelly $ silently $ do
    out <- run "foo" ["param1", "param2", "param3"] 
    -- lns will containes a list of lines with the stdout output of foo
    let lns = T.lines out
    -- Here we print out the number of lines and the first 5 lines
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ show $ Prelude.length lns
    liftIO $ mapM_ (putStrLn .T.unpack) $ take 5 lns
```